# How to search for a text in all rows, without specifying each column separately

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

E.g.

Given the following table and data, find the rows that contain the word 'on' (case insensitive)

```
create table t (i int,dt date,s1 string,s2 string,s3 string)
;

insert into t

select  inline
        (
            array
            (
                struct(1,date '2017-03-15','Now we take our time','so nonchalant','And spend our nights so bon vivant')
               ,struct(2,date '2017-03-16','Quick as a wink','She changed her mind','She stood on the tracks')
               ,struct(3,date '2017-03-17','But I’m talking a Greyhound','On the Hudson River Line','I’m in a New York state of mind')
            )
        ) 
;


select * from t
;

+-----+------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------+
| t.i |    t.dt    |            t.s1             |           t.s2           |                t.s3                |
+-----+------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------+
|   1 | 2017-03-15 | Now we take our time        | so nonchalant            | And spend our nights so bon vivant |
|   2 | 2017-03-16 | Quick as a wink             | She changed her mind     | She stood on the tracks            |
|   3 | 2017-03-17 | But I’m talking a Greyhound | On the Hudson River Line | I’m in a New York state of mind    |
+-----+------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

### The easy (but limited ) solution

This solution is relevant to tables that contain "primitive" types only
(no structs, arrays, maps etc.).

---

The problem with that solution is that all the columns are concatenated without separator (no, `concat_ws(*)` yields an exception) so words in the boundaries become a single word, e.g. -
`Greyhound` and `On` become `GreyhoundOn`

```
select  i
       ,regexp_replace(concat(*),'(?i)on','==>$0<==') as rec

from    t

where   concat(*) rlike '(?i)on'    
;
```

---

```
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   |                                                    rec                                                    |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | 12017-03-15Now we take our timeso n==>on<==chalantAnd spend our nights so b==>on<== vivant                |
| 2 | 22017-03-16Quick as a winkShe changed her mindShe stood ==>on<== the tracks                               |
| 3 | 32017-03-17But I’m talking a Greyhound==>On<== the Huds==>on<== River LineI’m in a New York state of mind |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### The complex (but agile) solution

This solution is relevant to tables that contain "primitive" types only
(no structs, arrays, maps etc.).

---

I pushed the envelope here but succeeded to generate a delimited string with all columns.
Now it is possible to look for whole words.

`(?ix)` http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

```
select  i
       ,regexp_replace(concat(*),'(?ix)\\b on \\b','==>$0<==') as delim_rec

from   (select  i
               ,printf(concat('%s',repeat('|||%s',field(unhex(1),*,unhex(1))-2)),*)   as delim_rec   

        from    t
        ) t

where  delim_rec rlike '(?ix)\\b on \\b'        
;
```

---

```
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| i |                                                    delim_rec                                                     |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2 | 22|||2017-03-16|||Quick as a wink|||She changed her mind|||She stood ==>on<== the tracks                         |
| 3 | 33|||2017-03-17|||But I’m talking a Greyhound|||==>On<== the Hudson River Line|||I’m in a New York state of mind |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### Using additional external table

```
create external table t_ext (rec string) 
row format delimited
fields terminated by '0'
location '/user/hive/warehouse/t'   
;
```

---

```
select  cast(split(rec,'\\x01')[0] as int)                                              as i
       ,regexp_replace(regexp_replace(rec,'(?ix)\\b on \\b','==>$0<=='),'\\x01','|||')  as rec

from    t_ext

where   rec rlike '(?ix)\\b on \\b'               
;
```

---

```
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| i |                                                       rec                                                       |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2 | 2|||2017-03-16|||Quick as a wink|||She changed her mind|||She stood ==>on<== the tracks                         |
| 3 | 3|||2017-03-17|||But I’m talking a Greyhound|||==>On<== the Hudson River Line|||I’m in a New York state of mind |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```